# How to convert a postgres database from CST to GMT?

Tags: postgresql

I setup a postgres db that was installed on a server in the Central Time Zone so all the timestamp columns are in Central Time Zone.

Is there a way in postgres to change all the timezone columns in a database from CST to GMT? Is it a best practice to configure databases to use GMT?

Comment: In `postgresql.conf`, there is a setting for timezone. So, you can do the following.`timezone = 'GMT'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, best practice is to avoid using `TIMESTAMP` type which does not know anything about timezones and to always use `TIMESTAMPTZ` (short for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`) type to store your timestamps.

`TIMESTAMPTZ` stores both timestamp in `UTC` and timezone in which timestamp was originally written to (like `CST`, `PST` or `GMT+6`). This allows you to always manipulate and display these columns correctly, no matter what current server or client timezone setting is.

You should be able to convert your existing TIMESTAMP columns into TIMESTAMPTZ using something like:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN old_tstamp TYPE TIMESTAMPTZ
```

Before doing this, you should experiment on small dataset or maybe small test table on how conversion from TIMESTAMP to TIMESTAMPTZ is really working for you such that time zone information is preserved on your data.

If conversion does not work correctly, you can temporarily set timezone for current session (you need it only for conversion purposes) using statement like (use it before `ALTER TABLE ... COLUMN ... TYPE`):

```
SET timezone TO 'CST6CDT';
```

or

```
SET timezone TO 'UTC+6';
```

This will affect subsequent operations and conversions from `TIMESTAMP` to `TIMESTAMPTZ` - just make sure to get it right.

After you have converted all timestamps to `TIMESTAMPTZ`, server or client timezone setting (which defaults to current operating system timezone setting) is only useful for display purposes, as data manipulation will be always correct.

Comment: all my ts times are actually already created with time zone, I was using a domain to create them, and did not really understand the finer points of the Timestamp with zone. looks like I have nothing to do other than change the time on the server.

Comment: "TIMESTAMPTZ stores both timestamp in UTC and timezone in which timestamp was originally written to (like CST, PST or GMT+6)." - that's not true, "For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC" ["8.5.1.3. Time Stamps"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5739).